# Find The Number of Binary Sequence

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I want to create a binary string of `0` and `1` , which will have `x` ones and `y` zeroes. 
A valid binary string such that at any length `i`  ,  `1<=i<=(x+y)` ,sum of occurrences of 
`1` is greater than `0`

```
For Ex  x=2 , y=1
110 // valid
101 // In valid because at 2 both occurrences are equal
```

Is there any direct formula for this ?

Comment: this is a variant of [Bertrand's Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_ballot_theorem)

Comment: Do you mean "The number of occurrences of $1$ is greater than the number of occurrences of $0$"?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter yes at every point

Comment: @lulu it should be strictly greater than

Comment: Right, that's the usual condition for Bertrand's result.